# How can I shorted my method code with any way in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Hi guys it is my addAll method and I think solving this way isn't optimize version, can you offer me a simpler version by the way. Any help into this would be appreciated!

```
@Override
public ApiResponse addAll(HttpHeaders headers, List<NewsDto> newsDtoList) {
    for (NewsDto newsDto : Objects.requireNonNull(newsDtoList)) {
        News news = new News();
        if (newsDto.getUserId() != null) news.setUserId(newsDto.getUserId());
        if (newsDto.getTitleRu() != null) news.setTitleRu(newsDto.getTitleRu());
        if (newsDto.getTextRu() != null) news.setTextRu(newsDto.getTextRu());
        if (newsDto.getTitleUz() != null) news.setTitleUz(newsDto.getTitleUz());
        if (newsDto.getTextUz() != null) news.setTextUz(newsDto.getTextUz());
        if (newsDto.getTitleEng() != null) news.setTitleEng(newsDto.getTitleEng());
        if (newsDto.getTextEng() != null) news.setTextEng(newsDto.getTextEng());
        newsRepo.save(news);
    }
    return new ApiResponse(true, "all list saved");
}
```

I try mapped with mapstruct but my entity class extend some fields at another class thats why mapstruct could't see any fields in class and I try solve this way.

Comment: Why you need the null check? why not use builder?

Comment: I'm pretty sure mapstruct is able to access and map inherited fields but without seeing your attempt it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: Also, what is the use of the null checks, e.g. what would be the difference between calling `news.setUserId(null)` (if `newsDto.getUserId()` would return `null`) and not calling the setter at all? Are there any additional checks or initial values in `News` other than `null`?

Comment: @user7294900   hi bro because when i send list of news where any value null method added null to database and I did it to prevent this situation. can i check null in builder?

Comment: Those `null` checks don't add anything, it doesn't prevent `null` from being inserted (unless you have set default values). Just use `MapStruct` to do this for you and provide the necessary information (fields to ignore etc).

Comment: @M. Deinum thank you bro how can i add the values in the header to mapstruct

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code slightly with the following considerations:

Your null checks aren't useful; if the field is null on one, it will be set to null on the other anyway. For example, in the original code you have:

```
if (newsDto.getUserId() != null) news.setUserId(newsDto.getUserId());
```

but if `newsDto.getUserId()` returns `null` then using this object on the setter doesn't change anything **unless a default value is already presesnt**.

So you can just write

```
News news = new News();
news.setUserId(newsDto.getUserId());
news.setTitleRu(newsDto.getTitleRu());
news.setTextRu(newsDto.getTextRu());
news.setTitleUz(newsDto.getTitleUz());
news.setTextUz(newsDto.getTextUz());
news.setTitleEng(newsDto.getTitleEng());
news.setTextEng(newsDto.getTextEng());
```

Or if you need some special logic for default values, you could make a method for that too

```
public String defaultValue(String raw) {
    if (raw == null || raw.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null; // or return an empty string or whatever you want
    }
    return raw;
}
```

Then you can use this in your mapping method

```
News news = new News();
news.setUserId(defaultValue(newsDto.getUserId()));
news.setTitleRu(defaultValue(newsDto.getTitleRu()));
news.setTextRu(defaultValue(newsDto.getTextRu()));
news.setTitleUz(defaultValue(newsDto.getTitleUz()));
news.setTextUz(defaultValue(newsDto.getTextUz()));
news.setTitleEng(defaultValue(newsDto.getTitleEng()));
news.setTextEng(defaultValue(newsDto.getTextEng()));
```

The above code should be in its own method, something like

```
public News toEntity(NewsDto newsDto) {
    ... // see above
    return news;
}
```

Then you can test this method for the conversion of one news dto to its respective entity class.

After that, use it in the loop you had:

```
@Override
public ApiResponse addAll(HttpHeaders headers, List<NewsDto> newsDtoList) {
    for (NewsDto newsDto : Objects.requireNonNull(newsDtoList)) {
        newsRepo.save(toEntity(newsDto));
    }
    return new ApiResponse(true, "all list saved");
}
```

Comment: thank you bro can i ask one more question how do I check that the value is not null. and you can also specify the version that can be solved via mapstruct ? - @geco17

Comment: you don't need to check for null unless you have default values. I updated the answer

Comment: I tried not to let the admins who were adding the news send empty lines, how dou you think have a another way it @geco17

Answer (score 0):

You could use ModelMapper. It should map your DTO to Entity as long as the variable names match.

```
private static final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

public static News convertNewsDTOToNewsEntity(NewsDTO newsDTO) {
    return modelMapper.map(newsDTO, News.class);
}
```